# Legend in horizontal multi bar chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I need to add a legend for this simple multi bar graph like,

[image]

I tried adding a legend just like in vertical bar chart. But i couldn't.

```
   jQuery(function($) {
   var names = ['John', 'Tim', 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Charles'],
   hotdogs = [8, 4, 9, 12, 11],
  chart,
   width = 400,
   bar_height = 20,
    height = bar_height * names.length;

    var x, y;

   x = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, d3.max(hotdogs)])
   .range([0, width]);

    y = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(hotdogs)
    .rangeBands([0, height]);

    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var left_width = 100;

    var gap = 2;
    y = d3.scale.ordinal()
     .domain(hotdogs)
      .rangeBands([0, (bar_height + 2 * gap) * names.length]);


    chart = d3.select($("#step-5")[0])
    .append('svg')
    .attr('class', 'chart')
     .attr('width', left_width + width + 40)
    .attr('height', (bar_height + gap * 2) * names.length + 30)
    .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(10, 20)");

     chart.selectAll("line")
     .data(x.ticks(d3.max(hotdogs)))
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return x(d) + left_width; })
    .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("y2", (bar_height + gap * 2) * names.length);

    chart.selectAll("rect")
   .data(hotdogs)
   .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", left_width)
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + gap; })
    .attr("width", x)
     .attr("height", bar_height)
     .style('fill', function(d) { 
      return color(d);
    });
```

How could i add a legend, which represents the color and the data it contains? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13573771/adding-a-chart-legend-in-d3) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a group bar chart with legend:

http://vida.io/documents/ZTqDgDxJtxpjsdt44

Legends are just rectangles with colors of bars in the chart.